# How to call the activity running on the top from Thread class

Tags: android

I am trying to start a thread in every activty oncreate method and after certain time  i want to finish the activty from the thread calss using finish() method but finish method needs to extend activty class.so, how can i get the activty on top in my thread class..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the activity to the thread in its constructor:

```
public MyThread( Activity activity ) {
   this.activity = activity;
}
```

And when you want to end the activity from the thread-class you call:

```
activity.finish();
```

Comment: thanks KasperMoerch ..i tried this way but its throwing null pointer at activity.finish();

Comment: As @Sevado says, post the stacktrace and the code for your thread class - Then we can provide more help.